# "Identifier is not defined" when using variable in gpu.js - why?

Tags: javascript, gpu.js

I am puzzled by an error I get with gpu.js. I am trying to do GPU-based calculations of nearest point on line, as I have to process hundreds of points against a line with thousands of segments.

See in-progress code at https://codepen.io/simonecesano/pen/rNeVKee

I stumble on the issue that - at line 48 if I do this:

```
var ptos = geodistance(fx, fy, sx, sy);
    
return geodistance(fx, fy, sx, sy);
```

everything works but if I do this:

```
var ptos = geodistance(fx, fy, sx, sy);
    
return ptos;
```

I get `Uncaught Error: Identifier is not defined` in gpu.browser.js

Why is that, and what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: This is weird. Can you try extracting those functions in global namespace?

Comment: @JimishFotariya - done: I extracted the kernel function, and ran it on the first point - no error. I can provide a gist if necessary

Comment: @JimishFotariya - could it be that I am hitting a limit on the number of variables allowed in a shader?

Comment: @JimishFotariya - it looks like doing `var ptos = 0; ptos = geodistance(fx, fy, sx, sy);` does not generate an error anymore, but I wish I knew why

Comment: ha ha, me too. Dont touch it now if its working ;)